# use .get() to get html of a div in another page

Tags: jquery, get, load

```
<script>
    $.get("link.html", function(data) {
      var data = $(data);
      //do something
      $("#Container").html(data);
    })
<script>
```

how can i get html of a div from another page to current page?
i used jquery load method but the scripts didn't executed.

sorry for bad English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$.get("link.html", function(data) {
    var html = $('<div>').html(data);
    var content = html.find("div#some_div_id").html();
    //do something
    $("#Container").html(content);
});
```

or you could use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), like

```
$('#Container').load('link.html #some_div_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$("#Container").load("link.html");
```

Comment: yes i try it and scripts working، but i want a part of html load to the div.