# Get text from body tag of another page hosted on another domain - javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Suppose a webpage **www.example.com/some.html** hosed on server. Now I want to get the content inside body tag of that page from another domain. How can I do it? I tried to find solution, but no luck with that yet.

Here are some ways that I thought and found.
First one can get content of a tag from same site.

```
    $.get("link.html", function(data) {
    var html = $('<div>').html(data);
    var content = html.find("div#some_div_id").html();
    //do something
    $("#Container").html(content);
});
```

[use .get() to get html of a div in another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399195/use-get-to-get-html-of-a-div-in-another-page)

I tried, but doesn't work for me. I think it's because of my cross domain request.

Second idea is using iframe. Wanna load the page into iframe and extract body tag. But can't find any solution regarding how can I detect the event that iframe completed loading the page? Or how can I get the content from an iframe loaded page?

**Can anyone please tell me how can I get those content from the body tag in a simple way?? Is there any solution just like my first example? Please help...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without a server-side proxy to request the other site's content; Javascript is not capable of making cross domain requests due to the same origin policy. You can't do this with an iframe or AJAX, server-side proxy only.

Comment: The above answers seem to work perfectly fine and they are implemented using the AJAX functions in jQuery. Is there something I'm not seeing here?

Comment: They are asking how to get the content of a site on a different domain using only javascript. The posted answers are not making cross-domain requests

Comment: I was able to load the page on iframe. Can't I extract it from there? Something like using this window.frames["myIFrame"].document; Unfortunately I can't detect the page load completion on iframe. @RobM.

Comment: You cannot, lots of people look into this, it's an important security feature

Comment: We're here to solve problems, not here to state that they are impossible. This is Stack Overflow, not parliament.

Comment: If you have an answer to their question other than "you can't do this with client-side javascript", please post it.

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
var bodycontent;
$("<div>").load("link.html body", function (data) {
  bodycontent = data;
});
```

If I was you, though, I would do it using something server-side. This is because many websites use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to block the files, and make you unable to access it. This is also a form of impersonation and hacking, so use it in moderation.

Comment: I don't have access of that server, so can't do anything on serverside. And this solution works on locally I checked it before.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax({
       url: "your_url",
       data: dataToSubmit,
       async: false,
       success: function(response) {
            $('.your_div').html(response);
       }
});
```

you may also use load

```
$('body').load("your_url");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("URL", function(data) {
  data = data.replace(/\n|\r|\t/gmi,'');
  /<body>(.*)<\/body>/i.test(data);
  data = RegExp.$1;
});
```

If you want parse HTML,using regular expressions is better

Comment: Of course,the 'URL' must be relative of your domain,$.ajax also not work.